# How to change parametric type during instantiation in Julia

Tags: types, julia, parameterized-constructor

I'm trying to do the following

```
type Foo{T}
  x::changeType(T)
end
```

where the function `changeType` changes the type parameter to some other type.  It doesn't have to be a function, I'm happy using a dictionary or a macro or w/e, I just need a way to do this.

I tried it with both a function and a dictionary and both resulted in errors.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is not entirely possible. However, you can play with a couple of workarounds.

1. Do not constrain the type of `x` and just instantiate `x` with the proper type manualy:

   ```
   type Foo{T}
       x
       y::T
   end

   >>> f = Foo{Int32}(5.0f0, 2)
   Foo{Int32}(5.0f0,2)
   >>> typeof(f.x), typeof(f.y)
   (Float32, Int32)
   ```
2. You can wrap your object in a function:

   ```
   const types = Dict(Int64 => Float32)

   type Foo{T}
       x::T
   end

   foo(k) = Foo{get(types, T, T)}
   ```

   Then create an object of `Foo`

   ```
   >>> foo(Int64)
   Foo{Float32}
   ```
3. If you want to have mixed type fields in the same `type` (e.g. fields of `T` and `map(T)`) you can modify a bit the constructor:

   ```
   const types = Dict(Int64 => Float32)

   type Foo{T}
       x
       y::T

       Foo(x=0, y=0) = new(get(types, T, T)(x), y)
   end
   ```

   This will allow you to create `Foo` as `Foo{Int64}` while mapping `x` to `Float32`:

   ```
   >>> Foo{Int64}(5, 2)
   Foo{Int64}(5.0f0, 2)     # x is Float32, y is Int64
   ```
4. And the last, and probably the most viable one: first define the dictionary and wrap your `type` in both `types`:

   ```
   const types = Dict(Int64 => Float32)

   type Foo{T, V}
       x::V
       y::T
   end
   ```

   Now wrap the construction of a `Foo` object into a function:

   ```
   foo(T) = Foo{T, get(types, T, T)}
   foo(T, args...) = Foo{T, get(types, T, T)}(args...)
   ```

   `foo` function creates objects of type `Foo` where the first parameter specifies the type `T` of `Foo` and the type `V` is dynamically inferred from the `types` dictionary.

   ```
   >>> foo(Int64)
   Foo{Int64,Float32}
   >>> foo(Int64, 5, 2)
   Foo{Int64,Float32}(5.0f0,2) # x is Float32, y is Int64
   ```

---

Note: in both the above methods, if `T` is not defined in the `types` dictionary, the `get` function returns `T` and thus `x` is mapped to `T`. Is a fall-back method for types that don't require mapping. E.g. for the third option:

```
>>> Foo{Int32}(5, 2)
Foo{Int32}(5,2)
```

both `x` and `y` are `Int32` since `Int32` is not in the mapping dict `types`. And for the fourth option:

```
>>> foo(Int32)
Foo{Int32,Int32}
```

---

I think currently the type of `x` cannot be specified at compile time as a function of `T`, but the above workarounds should do the job.

I don't know neither how smart is the Julia compiler.. given that the `types` dictionary is constant, it might do some smart things and infer the type of `x` from there (maybe a dev could answer this or give further improvements).

Comment: `const types = Dict(…)` doesn't make the dictionary immutable — it just means that the binding `types` will always refer to that one dictionary.  So Julia cannot do any compile-time reasoning about type transformations like that.  If you want to make this type-stable, you can use method dispatch instead: `change_type{T}(::Type{T}) = T; change_type(::Type{Int64}) = Float64`.

Comment: @MattB. Wow thanks for the clarification. I was assuming that `const` would make the dict immutable, but tried it in a terminal and as you said, it allows me to add new items. The `change_type` you mention is probably the best option to replace the dictionary :)